# SSRS Subscription Fails

Tags: subscription, ssrs

Our SSRS server is not executing a subscription correctly.  (Only subscription we have btw)

We created a subscription to export a report as an excel file to the file system.

Tried running the job that gets generated, and this error happens

> 'EXECUTE AS LOGIN' failed for the
> requested login 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK
> SERVICE'.  The step failed.

It's not the most helpful in tracking down what exactly it was trying to do.

### EDIT

Digging further into the logs I also get these errors

> w3wp!extensionfactory!f!7/30/2010-14:29:26::
> w WARN: The extension Report Server
> FileShare does not have a
> LocalizedNameAttribute.
>
> w3wp!extensionfactory!11!7/30/2010-14:34:48::
> w WARN: The extension Report Server
> Email does not have a
> LocalizedNameAttribute.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you don't have an Execution account setup, and the SSRS service is setup to run under a local account, and the report is setup to use the Windows Auth of the person running the report to log into the database.

Try setting an Execution Account within the SSRS Configuration Manager.